# Google Analytics Schema for Purchases

Tags: google-analytics

I'm not very familiar with Google Analytics. I'm trying to figure out what the schema would look like for an export that contains all purchases for any users that have visited my site. So to sum it up, I'm interested in understanding what the data structure will look like (column names) for an export from GA that contains all purchases on my site.

Thank you in advance for any insight you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no export schema for Google Analytics as such, but the best source for this could be BigQuery Export Schema (BigQuery is included in the Premium/360 version of GA).

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

You will be able to access it even if you are not GA360 paying customer. The export schema is pretty solid, however keep in mind that there are some vital dimensions that are not available through API/GA interface by default.

Hope this helps.